# How to schedule a job with Flask on Windows?

Tags: python, flask, cron, scheduled-tasks

It seems that flask-crontab cannot run on my machine because there is no such thing as a windows cron.

This is the error I get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'`

If this is the case, how can I write a scheduled job in a Flask application?

Specifically, I need to be able to deploy the application--so it won't be running on windows once it goes into production, but in the meantime, I can't debug if I can't test the cronjob on my own computer.

Any help is appreciated, e.g. pointing me to documentation that is useful, suggesting other extensions, etc. Thanks!

Pete

Comment: There are several things here that seem not to make sense, but generally: If developing in the same OS you're going to deploy to isn't feasible or desirable to you, you should _at the very least_ have a testing/staging environment that's as similar as possible to production so you can effectively test before deployment.

Comment: I'm new to this--is there a platform other than Heroku that's friendlier to apps developed in a windows environment?

Comment: That'd presumably mean a platform that runs on Windows, and that's not a platform I'd ever use or recommend. It's not a good idea to constrain your deployment platforms based on using Windows for development... if it's an option at all, definitely try switching to Linux for development. It'll make local testing a lot easier and more useful, and you'll be far better equipped to work with almost every deployment environment out there.

Comment: Gotcha, I will definitely keep that in mind down the line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you start using **Celery**,

Celery is a great library to use for job scheduling, whether you want this job to be periodic or upon request tasks.

[Follow this guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/patterns/celery/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Apache Airflow**. It is written in Python. Its documentation is [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/).